# Updating ubuntu 13.10 Problem on Dell E6410

Tags: updates, software-installation

When ever I try to update, I get this message:

```
W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu-GNOME 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release amd64 (20131017)/dists/saucy/main/binary-amd64/Packages
Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu-GNOME 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release amd64 (20131017)/dists/saucy/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages
Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu-GNOME 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release amd64 (20131017)/dists/saucy/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages
Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu-GNOME 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release amd64 (20131017)/dists/saucy/universe/binary-amd64/Packages
Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu-GNOME 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release amd64 (20131017)/dists/saucy/main/binary-i386/Packages
Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu-GNOME 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release amd64 (20131017)/dists/saucy/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages
Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu-GNOME 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release amd64 (20131017)/dists/saucy/restricted/binary-i386/Packages
Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu-GNOME 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release amd64 (20131017)/dists/saucy/universe/binary-i386/Packages
Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Though i have internet connection. What would be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal CTRL+ALT+T then run the following command:

```
gksu software-properties-gtk
```

a small window will open type your user password then a window will open called software sources uncheck cdrom and uncheck the two ppas that failed to fetch below. [image: software sources]

http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages 404 Not Found , W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages 
Then do:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```